# Applying the default variables pattern to mixins in SASS

Tags: css, sass

In SASS, one of the features is the ability to create default variables:

```
$mycolor: #000000 !default;
```

Like this, if `$mycolor` is already defined, its value will not be changed.

#### Theming

This feature is interesting as allows designers to leverage themes. Say you application supports different color schemes, so you can have a common color scheme `_def.scss`:

```
$header-color: #ff9900 !default;
$text-color: #000000 !default;
$footer-color: #ffcc00 !default;
```

And different themes like `happy/_theme.scss`:

```
$header-color: #cc0000 !default;
$footer-color: #dd0000 !default;
```

The import must happens in this order:

```
@import "happy/theme";
@import "def";
```

First the theme, then the defaults.

#### How about mixins

I would like to apply the same logic with minins. As I already have themes for colors, I want them for fonts.

```
@mixin text-font !default {
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  font-weight: normal;
}
```

So I could override it in themes. But it is not possible to use `!default` on mixins.

How can I achieve this design? Again, the reason as I am stubborn on `!default` is because I already have a structure with themes in place and would like to reuse it.

Comment: how about `$font = Arial !default; @mixin text-font { font-family: $font; }`